# How can we create the back button in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

Can any one tell me how can I create the back button in my portlet. Are there any existing tags to create the back button which looks like as shared below.

[image]

Comment: Where do you want use redirect / back URL? Is it a default portlet or custom portlet?

Comment: @parakash Kumar In my custom portlet which is deployed under control panel.

Comment: Create a renderURL in your main view, pass it as request parameter and get on second jsp, assign this url to the a / button. This URL will work as back URL on current page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution as mentioned in below post should work.

http://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/22392288

Liferay uses back URL in many of its default portlets. 
For example, You can refer sources for message board portlet - view.jsp, edit_category.jsp

If you use  to move from first JSP to second JSP, then backURL should be passed as argument in first JSP and retrieve in second JSP to use inside liferay-ui:header tag.

For example,

```
<portlet:renderURL var="varURL"> 
<portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="<second-JSP-URL>"></portlet:param>
<portlet:param name="backURL" value="<%= themeDisplay.getURLCurrent() %>"></portlet:param>
</portlet:renderURL>
```

Comment: Lets resolve one by one. Which theme did you apply for page ? It should be Welcome-theme to get the icon that you mentioned in query.

Comment: Theme is applied to page not portlet. You need to make sure first that your portlet is on a page for which Welcome Theme is applied. you can click on edit page and see the current theme applied to page

Comment: Can you tell me what theme selected for control panel ? Go to: Control Panel → Portal Settings → Display Settings → Look and Feel → Default Control Panel Theme

Comment: Default Control Panel Theme is "control panel"

Comment: shall I change it to "Welcome"

Comment: I tried by changing the default theme to "Welcome" still I am not be able to see the back button icon. I am able to see only the label

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75293/discussion-between-haris-and-vinod).

Comment: I' am getting this error with this solution:




    13:06:58,436 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-22][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
javax.portlet.PortletException: Path /web/guest/home?....[correct path and jsp name]jsp is not accessible by this portlet

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead.
Just use one line and it will direct back to previous URL.(Place this code in second jsp).

```
<input type=button value=" Back" onClick="javascript: window.history.go(-1)" text-align="right">
```

Comment: You say "this code", but there isn't any code in your answer. Could you please put the code in that will solve the problem? Thanks.